# How to make route request as username in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to make a Authentication System on RoR. So the main problem is the route. I need to make my url like:

```
http://www.example.com/username
```

I have tried and finished with result:

```
http://www.example.com/user/username
```

How to remove the "/user/" part?

Comment: Just need to point out that putting the username into the url seems like quite bad security.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "" #-> yoursite.com/username
```

You can also use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) **gem** for more complete solution.

Comment: Thanks you, very much!